# Counting the quantity of the items from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with 2 columns and it looks like this

```
C1 C2
 A  1
 B  2
 A  3
 A  1
 C  4
 A  2
 C  1
```

Now, I have form a table which contains the quantity of the items

Such as,

```
item   Quantity
   A          7
   B          2
   C          5
```

Please help with this!

Comment: Simple Google search would have given the answer.

Comment: I just want to add the values of C2 with same value of C1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need `aggregate`

```
aggregate(df$c2, list(df$c1), sum)

#  Group.1 x
#1       A 7
#2       B 2
#3       C 5
```

Or as the @thelatemail suggested to preserve the column names you can use

```
aggregate(c2 ~ c1, data=df, sum)

#c1 c2
#1  A  7
#2  B  2
#3  C  5
```

Comment: Or `aggregate(c2 ~ c1, data=df, sum)` or `aggregate(df["c2"], df["c1"], sum)`